# Database insert with MySQL

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I created a pos system a while a go , and i created a query , after creating it i started to get this fatal error while i run the program.
Here is some code>

```vb
  Private Sub IzmeniArtikal()

    konekcija = New MySqlConnection
    konekcija.ConnectionString =
        "server=localhost;userid=root;password=1234;database=baza;port=3307"
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Dim kupovnacena As Double
    Dim prodaznacena As Double
    Dim kolicina As Double
    Dim profit As Double
    Dim ddv As Double
    Dim mkpr As String
    Try
        konekcija.Open()
        If TextBoxBarkod.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето баркод е празно , внеси баркод или шифра!", "Грешка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub

        End If
        If TextBoxNaziv.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето назив на артикал  е празно , внеси назив на артикал!", "Грешка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBoxKupovna.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето  набавна цена  е празно , внеси набавна цена !", "Грешка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If TextBoxProdazna.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето  продажна цена  е празно , внеси продажна цена !", "Грешка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub
        End If



        If TextBoxKolicina.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето количина  е празно , внеси количина!", "Грешка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            Exit Sub
        End If




        If Not IsNumeric(TextBoxBarkod.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето баркод/шифра мора да содржи само бројки.", "Инфо", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If Not IsNumeric(TextBoxKolicina.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето количина мора да содржи само бројки.", "Инфо", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBoxKupovna.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето набавна цена мора да содржи само бројки.", "Инфо", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If Not IsNumeric(TextBoxProdazna.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Полето продажна цена мора да содржи само бројки.", "Инфо", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Exit Sub
        End If



        kolicina = TextBoxKolicina.Text

        kupovnacena = TextBoxKupovna.Text
        prodaznacena = TextBoxProdazna.Text

        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then

            ddv += prodaznacena * 0.18


        End If
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then

            ddv += prodaznacena * 0.05


        End If
        If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then


            mkpr = "Да"

        End If

        profit = prodaznacena - kupovnacena


        If kupovnacena > prodaznacena Then
            MessageBox.Show("Набавната цена не смее да е поголема од продажната цена", "Грешка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
            TextBoxKupovna.Text = ""
            TextBoxProdazna.Text = ""
            Exit Sub


        End If
        If ComboBox1.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Одбери тип на ДДВ ", "Инфо, внеси тип на ДДВ !!! ", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim Query As String

        Query = "insert into baza.artikli
    (kod,naziv,nabavna,prodazna,ddv,kolicina,opis,
     opis2,mkproizvod,profit,proizvoditel) values 
    (@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6,@p7,@p8,@p9,@p10,@p11)"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxBarkod.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxNaziv.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p3", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxKupovna.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p4", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxProdazna.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p5", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddv
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p6", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxKolicina.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p7", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxOpis.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p8", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxOpis2.Text
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p9", MySqlDbType.String).Value = mkpr
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p10", MySqlDbType.Double).Value = profit
        COMMAND.Parameters.Add("@p11", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxProizvoditel.Text



        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader



        MessageBox.Show("Артиклот е успешно променет !", "Успешно променет артикал", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        TextBoxBarkod.Text = ""
        TextBoxKupovna.Text = ""
        TextBoxNaziv.Text = ""
        TextBoxOpis.Text = ""
        TextBoxProdazna.Text = ""
        TextBoxProizvoditel.Text = ""
        TextBoxKolicina.Text = ""
        TextBoxOpis2.Text = ""
        ComboBox1.Text = ""
        ComboBox2.Text = ""
        konekcija.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        prikazitabela()
        konekcija.Dispose()

    End Try



End Sub
```

Comment: There is usually more to the error message.  For one thing though, a Textbox will never be containing a Double for the p1 or p6 parameters.  You should also read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: I still get the same error after i change from double to varchar

Comment: As I said, there is usually more to those if you look at the details/inner exception.  Without that info, we are guessing - like the connection being opened is not shown.

Comment: I just updated the question with all the details and the whole method

Comment: Set `Option Strict On` and correct the compiling errors

Comment: You should work to make it easy for people to read your post to give you an answer.  That at least means to format it as code - there is plenty of help and a preview in the editor.